# Spark NaiveBayesTextClassification

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i'm trying to create a text classifier spark(1.6.2) app, but I don't know what am I doing wrong. This is my code:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.{NaiveBayes, NaiveBayesModel}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SQLContext}
import org.apache.spark.mllib
import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{HashingTF, IDF, Tokenizer}


/**
  * Created by kebodev on 2016.11.29..
  */
object PredTest {

  def  main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setMaster("local[*]")
      .setAppName("IktatoSparkRunner")
      .set("spark.executor.memory", "2gb")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    val trainData = sqlContext.read.json("src/main/resources/tst.json")

    val tokenizer = new Tokenizer().setInputCol("text").setOutputCol("words")
    val wordsData = tokenizer.transform(trainData)
    val hashingTF = new HashingTF()
      .setInputCol("words").setOutputCol("features").setNumFeatures(20)
    val featurizedData = hashingTF.transform(wordsData)


    val model = NaiveBayes.train(featurizedData)

  }

}
```

The `NaiveBayes` object doesn't have train method, what should I import?

If i try to use this way:

```
 val naBa = new NaiveBayes()
    naBa.fit(featurizedData)
```

I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Column label must be of type DoubleType but was actually StringType.
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.SchemaUtils$.checkColumnType(SchemaUtils.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PredictorParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(Predictor.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.Classifier.org$apache$spark$ml$classification$ClassifierParams$$super$validateAndTransformSchema(Classifier.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.ClassifierParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(Classifier.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.ProbabilisticClassifier.org$apache$spark$ml$classification$ProbabilisticClassifierParams$$super$validateAndTransformSchema(ProbabilisticClassifier.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.ProbabilisticClassifierParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(ProbabilisticClassifier.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.ProbabilisticClassifier.validateAndTransformSchema(ProbabilisticClassifier.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.transformSchema(Predictor.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage.transformSchema(Pipeline.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:89)
    at PredTest$.main(PredTest.scala:37)
    at PredTest.main(PredTest.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

This is how my json file looks like:

```
{"text":"any text","label":"6.0"}
```

I'm really noob in this topic. Can anyone help me how to create a model, and then how to predict a new value.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Labels and Feature Vectors only contain Doubles. Your label column contains a String.

See your stacktrace:

```
Column label must be of type DoubleType but was actually StringType.
```

You can use the `StringIndexer` or `CountVectorizer` to convert it appropriately. See http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#stringindexer for further details.

Comment: Thank you, I created this: renamed the label field in my cs file to labelstring and add value 6 then i create this val indexer = new StringIndexer()
      .setInputCol("labelstring")
      .setOutputCol("label")

    val indexed = indexer.fit(featurizedData).transform(featurizedData) but when it prints out the label value is 0.0 why is that?

Comment: and then how can i use the model? :) there isn't any predict and train method.. :(

Comment: 0.0 is the label for the first class which is contained in the label column and 1.0 is the second and so on.

Comment: Ahh, i underdtand it! :) can you tell me where are train and predict methods ? Thank you!

Comment: Every ML algorithm is a Pipeline element that has to be fitted first to the data (this is equivalent to the training) and then can be applied to other data in order to transform it (this is the equivalent to the prediction method, you are looking for). It is basically the same as with the StringIndexer which you already used correctly. In general i would advise you to have a look at the Pipeline concepts of Spark which are really nice.